# How to randomize animation once at a time only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm new to jquery. I have a value in array as

`var obj = [{'com':'something'},{'com':'some other thing'}];`

and my animation as like this : https://codepen.io/R4ver/pen/EHlpF?page=8

i want to append the above obj array values to the animation how to show in a sequence one by one ., i created animation but can't able to append the animation

i tried this one but it simply alert the com values( i want to miggle with the animation as above) :

```
$.each(obj, function(key,value) {
   alert(value.com);
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find your jquery array in the codepen.

you should have an **interval** and loop through the array and show the results one by one.

your codes should be like this:

```
var substr = ['hello','how are you?', 'what is your name?', 'have a good time'];
var x = -1;
setInterval(function() {
if (x < substr.length - 1){
x++;
substr[x]; 
$('.text').delay(2500).queue(function(next){            
$('.text').addClass('load');
$('.text').text(' ');
next(); 
});
$('.text').text(substr[x]);
$('.text').removeClass('load');  
}else{
x = -1;            
}            
}, 5000);
```

visit this codepen for a working example:
https://codepen.io/nabilou/pen/EoJJPz